# PDO Check if data exist if not create

Tags: php, ajax, function, pdo

So what I want is that I would like it to check if the person already used the code, If it has been used, then it should die, otherwise set the data from              `$_POST['code']` and lock it, so it can't changed again - (But only by deleting the data in the database)

Database name = users

In users, I have a structure setup with code_used

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('assets/includes/include.php');

if(isset($_POST['code'])) {
$SQLCheckExistens = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `code_used` = :code");
$SQLCheckExistens -> execute(array(':code' => $_POST['code']));
$countCodes = $SQLCheckExistens -> fetchColumn(0);

if($countCodes = 0) {
    $SQLRedeemCode = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `code_used` = :code WHERE `steamid` = :SteamID");
    $SQLRedeemCode -> execute(array(':code' => $_POST['code'], ':SteamID' => $_SESSION['steamid']));

    die('Saved successfully!');
} else { 
    die('Error. You have already redeemed a code.'); 
}   
} else {
die();
}
?>
```

Here is the ajax

```
<script>            
function SetCode() {
var code = document.getElementById('code').value;

$.ajax( {
    type: 'post',
    url: 'redeem.php',
    data: "code=" + code,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        document.getElementById('data_response').innerHTML = response;          
    }
});
}
```

Here is the function

```
function getCode($UserID, $odb)
{
    $SQLUserInfo = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid` = :SteamID");
    $SQLUserInfo -> execute(array(':SteamID' => $UserID));
    $UserInfo = $SQLUserInfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $UserInfo['code_used'];
}
```

Comment: So, where is the question?

Comment: It will not let me just type in something once, as you can edit it by changing the code in the textbox.
After you have typed a code, you cant use others, so that the question. I dont know how to create it.

Comment: What errors or what is stopping you from achieving this?

Comment: I don't know, it wont tell me, as it just UPDATES the data in my database. So I claimed the code : 1234  - it accepts and writes it into my database. But when i turn back to the site i try to type in 4534, and then it just replaces 1234 to 4534, which should not be possible, as it should only be possible to claim once.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a value in you if statement which will return a true in your case. It should be:

```
if($countCodes == 0) { // UPDATE SQL ...
```

Try using the `COUNT` returned from MySQL. Or, you could use [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

```
$SQLCheckExistens = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `code_used` = :code");
$SQLCheckExistens -> execute(array(':code' => $_POST['code']));
$result = $SQLCheckExistens -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$countCodes = $result[0];
```

Comment: But it still keeps changing the value, when I enter a new "redeem code"

Comment: what does `$countCodes` return? @MikkelBertelsen

Comment: It does not work yet. $countCodes should return if no data = Insert the redeemed code you typed in - If it finds data, then it should just come up with the message: You have already redeemed a code. and NOT update it.

Comment: @MikkelBertelsen The code does just like what you said. if $countCodes = 0(0 records found) then update, else error